# Nested if statement within a while loop is executing irrespective of wether the if statement is satisfied or not. What am i missing here?

Tags: while-loop, nested-if

instead of just saying `sorry` if no 'if condition' in the while loop is satisfied, it just keeps speaking `Dash`. when it understands it gives correct response but when it doesn't, it just says `dash` instead of saying `sorry`. what am i doing wrong? Do i have to break the nested if ?

UPDATE: I found the problem guys. Still the problem doesn't explain this weird behavior.

the problem is multiple checks in an if or an elif statement. in the below example, elif statement `elif 'start' or 'started' in recorded_audio:` the program checks for both `start` and `started` in two different strings using `or`. If I modify the above statement to be `elif 'start started' in recorded_audio:`, everything works as it should normally. Why does it happen like this ?? How do I solve this ?? I need to be able to use `and` and `or` in my loops. This is for a very sophisticated medical algorithm to be used by doctors in the clinics, I just want to get the foundation right before performing checks with my database models. Any help is deeply appreciated. thanks.

```
def speak(transcription):
    tts = gTTS(text=transcription, lang='en', tld='co.uk')
    r = random.randint(1,1000000)
    audio_file = "voice" + str(r) + ".mp3"
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound(audio_file)
    os.remove(audio_file)

def record_audio():
    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, args.samplerate)
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            transcript = rec.Result()
            transcribed_dict = json.loads(transcript)
            transcribed_text = transcribed_dict.get('text')
            print(transcribed_text)
            return(transcribed_text)

stream = sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize = 8000, device=args.device, dtype='int16', channels=1, callback=callback)
    with stream:

        stream.stop()
        speak('Hello sir, How may I help you ?')
        stream.start()

        while True:
            x = record_audio()
            recorded_audio = x.lower()
            stream.stop()
            
            if 'hello' in recorded_audio:
                speak('Apple')
            
            elif 'how are you' in recorded_audio:
                speak('Bat')
                stream.start()
                response = record_audio()
                stream.stop()
                if 'alright' or 'all right' or 'fine' in response:
                    speak('Cat')

            elif 'start' or 'started' in recorded_audio:
                speak('Dash')
          
            else:
                speak('sorry')

            stream.start()
```

Comment: `elif 'start' or 'started' in recorded_audio`  This condition will always be true: it works like `elif ('start') or ('started' in recorded_audio)`, not like `elif ('start' in recorded_audio) or ('started' in recorded_audio)`.

Comment: Hey slothrop, thanks for the reply. How do I rewrite this to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could write `elif ('start' in recorded_audio) or ('started' in recorded_audio)`.  However, this is the same as just doing `elif 'start' in recorded_audio`.  Because if a string contains 'started', then of course it contains 'start' too.  You might want to consider breaking the text up into a list of words rather than using it as a single string.

Comment: Thanks slothrop, makes sense. could I be able to use the slice() method to do it and then use a for loop to cycle through the list of works, checking their presence in recorded_audio ???

Comment: `.split()` is what you want to form the list of words.  Then you can write statements like `if 'start' in word_list or 'started' in word_list` without a loop.

Comment: thank you slothrop. I am accepting you answer. But it is a comment so, I have to post my own answer I suppose.